# "Build" action of any skill in developer console takes a very very long time (more than 15 mins) and eventually fails

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

The "Build" action of any skill in developer console under my account takes a very very long time (more than 15 mins) and eventually fails with no detailed error message. Only says ""Build failed for skill " with red text in the popup box lower right.
Even right after I created a new skill, the same above Build problem occurs.
All of my skills are English (CA) as primary locale.
It wasn't like this several days ago. Build normally only takes 1 minute or so.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Normally Build the skill after some changes.
Expecting it Builds normally as usual (fast and successful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to a service outage on Amazon side. A fix has been deployed that should resolve this issue. If you do find any issue persists, I recommend clearing out your browser's cache and re-starting. Steps to do so for the three main browsers can be found here:

- Microsoft Edge: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10607/microsoft-edge-view-delete-browser-history
- Google Chrome: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en
- Mozilla Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox